# How to import the dateutil.rrule module in Python

Tags: python, module

Following the [rrule examples](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#rrule-examples), I've noticed I can import the `rrule` object in this fashion:

```
from dateutil.rrule import *
my_rrule = rrule(DAILY, count=5)
print(list(my_rrule))
```

which prints the expected output

```
[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 23, 16, 55, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 24, 16, 55, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 25, 16, 55, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 26, 16, 55, 30), datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 27, 16, 55, 30)]
```

However, I like to maintain references to the module, so instead I'm trying to import and use it like this:

```
import dateutil.rrule
my_rrule = dateutil.rrule.rrule(DAILY, count=5)
```

However, this leads to a `NameError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kurt/dev/scratch/Furion_scheduler/recurring_interval.py", line 18, in <module>
    my_rrule = dateutil.rrule.rrule(DAILY, count=5)
NameError: name 'DAILY' is not defined
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY`.

Comment: It looks like the OP wants `from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY`.

Comment: I see. `DAILY`, which actually corresponds to the number `3`, is defined in the `dateutil.rrule` module (see [source code](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/dateutil/rrule.html#rrule)).